# Items in drop down lists of combo box are all empty

Tags: wpf

The drop down boxes seems to show the correct number of entries as in the list it binds to but all entries are empty. No string visible.

If Selected property also works like the strings are there but the strings are not visible in combobox.

Answer (score -1):

This happens if the items in structure that binds to combobox are not declared as properties (they are simple fields).